# ajax control toolkit calendar for dynamically generated textboxes

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have one problem.I have 30 dynamically generated textboxes as table rows in c#.net. for each of them i need to provide calendar tool. i am trying to use ajax calendar control.but it is not working.can u suggest me how to do and also some sample code?

Answer (score 4):

if i want to create a Text box form code behind we simple create an object of Text Box for example

```
 TextBox txtDate = new TextBox();
        txtDate.ID = "txtDate";
        phDate.Controls.Add(txtDate); // here phDate is a Place holder on Aspx Page
        //Now we need to add a Ajax Calendar Extender at Text Box so we should add Calendar dynamically on the code behind.



 AjaxControlToolkit.CalendarExtender calenderDate = new AjaxControlToolkit.CalendarExtender();
        calenderDate.ID = "calenderDate";
        calenderDate.TargetControlID = "txtDate";
        calenderDate.Format = "dd/MM/yyy";
        phDate.Controls.Add(calenderDate);]
```

Comment: At first I thought this was part of the initial posters question, so I posted an answer, but I ended up testing your code instead. Your code is working fine for me. I had to use the toolkit script manager control.  It does not work for me if I use a regular script manager control, which is probably normal.

Comment: Yeah, you have to use "ToolkitScriptManager" and accept the answer if you got the solution.